# Pronouncing 'OR' with an Indian accent

Tags: pronunciation, accent

I am familiar with the British as well as American pronunciation of the word **or.**
British people pronounce the **r** sound very lightly, whereas Americans tend to *roll their tongue.*

But interacting with fellow Indian people, when I try to pronounce it either way I sound utterly weird.

How should I pronounce it in Indian English?

Comment: Presumably because American English is a [rhotic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rhotic) dialect. You should pronounce it  as other Indian English speakers do, of course!

Comment: "British people pronounce the r sound very lightly" or don't pronounce it at all...

Comment: One of the things that makes Indian English accents distinctive is the common use of  retroflex consonants where most Englishes use alveolar ones (ट rather than त for English 't', for example). I believe that some speaker also use a retroflex 'r'. In any case, as Kate says, pronouncing /r/ as your neighbours do will work better for you than trying to choose a foreign realisation.

Comment: @ColinFine so you mean to say that there is no set of rules for Indian pronunciation. It arbitrary, and I will have to learn it from my neighbors.

Comment: Yes, It is exactly the same for RP  and General American pronunciation.  There are no rules and it is learned from neighbours (or more often, parents)  But with high status dialects there tends to be 1) More descriptive work on the dialect and 2) prescriptive texts that teach the dialect.  With low status dialects there are fewer of (1) and almost no (2)

Comment: There are multiple Indian Englishes. You can hear both rhotic and arhotic ones.